# Unable to POST from Angular UI to ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, fetch

I am trying to POST an object from my Angular app to an ASP.NET WebApi but I get the following error.

> Failed to load http://localhost:64859/api/comments: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

In the .service.ts, I am sending a POST with fetch().

```
fetch(this.Url, {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify(obj), 
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' // Do I need this?
  } 
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.text());
  return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log('Error:', data);
});
```

This is the controller in my API.

```
// POST api/<controller>
[HttpPost]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public string Post([FromBody]Obj obj)
{ ... }
```

In Startup.cs...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
            builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin(); });
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess You have to put "AddCors" or "UseCors" before "AddMvc" / "UseMvc"
something like this:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder =>
            {
                 builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyOrigin();
            }));
services.AddMvc();
```

or in Configure method

```
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
app.UseMvc();
```

and change this part

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

to

```
[EnableCors("AllowAllOrigins")]
```

and don't set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in fetch

try this and tell me the result